# Simply convert 5 digit number in mysql database to a date

Tags: mysql, excel, date, format

I have been looking all over the web for this answer but dont understand all the things that were written. I try to do the from unix_timestamp() but it returns the wrong date.
What I have done is import a xls file into the database. It converted the date to a 5 digit number. 
Is there a simple way? Any help would be great. 
This is what I have tried. I tried changing the date format in the excel file to YYYY-MM-DD and this did not work.

Comment: What do you mean "this did not work"?

Comment: I changed it to that format then imported the file again and it still went into the database as a 5 digit number

Comment: What's the data type of the MySQL field?

Comment: Now its just giving me all zeros

Comment: Try to make it a varchar and see what gets imported. After that you can figure out what the date format is and convert it. The five digit number might be the standard excel way of storing dates (days since 1900 or something).

Answer (score 3):

To go from Excel values, try this:

```
select date('1899-12-30') + interval <number> days
```

For instance:

```
select date('1899-12-30') + interval 40000 days
```

Returns July 6, 2009, just as it does in Excel.

In other words, you can bring the value in as an integer and then do the conversion in SQL.

I'm actually a little surprised because the 0 date on Excel is essentially Jan 0, 1900, which is Dec 31, 1899.  I suspect there is an issue with the lack of leap year in 1900.  Excel has the value of "60" represented as Feb 29,1900.  This is amusing, I hadn't realized that Excel had this bug.

So, the above code works, for all values greater than 61.

Comment: The Sands of time: Apparently, during prehistoric times, Microsoft desktop forms and spreadsheets use(d!) a '01Jan1900' start date calendar clock whereas the IEEE folks swear(swore!) by '01Jan1960'  ergo your delta 60 years number of days!

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
        $date_format = floor($excelDateTime);
        $time_format = $excelDateTime - $date_format;
        $mysql_strdate = ($date_format > 0) ? ( $date_format - 25569 ) * 86400 + $time_format * 86400 :    $time_format * 86400;
        $mysql_date_format = date("Y-d-m", $mysql_strdate);
```