# Convert 5 digit number to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize in advance because I am sure this question has been asked before, but I don't know the name of the type of date I am working with.

How do I convert a date in this 5-digit form (e.g. 41867) into a regular yyyy-dd-mm in SQL Server?

Comment: So how does that number 41867 convert to a date?

Comment: Are these epoch dates from linux? What date should 41867 be??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589834/simply-convert-5-digit-number-in-mysql-database-to-a-date

Comment: That looks like an Excel serial date - days since 1st January 1900. There is another format which is a 2-digit year followed by a 3-digit day number (99001 is 1st Jan 1999, for example), but the OP's example won't work for that format

Comment: Is "41687" coming from Excel and representing the date "2014-08-16", by any chance? Then `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 41867, '18991230')` should do what you want. Possibly with some conversion to `DATE`.

Comment: @HoboSapiens the dates are probably Excel dates. I don't know what exact dates they are supposed to convert to

Comment: It's rather crucial that you do know what dates they are supposed to be... otherwise, how will you ever know if they're right? Try to find at least one instance where you can obviously tell what the right date should be from the surrounding data.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that works, thanks, as long as '18991230'  is the correct starting point. I don't get any errors but I don't know the exact dates it is supposed to be converting to, so I am not sure if it works correctly

Comment: The possible duplicate thread does not work for me, it is in MySQL, this is for SQL Server

Comment: Per @benjaminmoskovits below, that date could *also* be "2014-08-18", if the starting point is 1900-01-01. I simply entered "41867" in Excel and had it display as a date; the outcome of that is "2014-08-16". This is not exactly scientific. That's why you need to know where that value is coming from and what it represents.

Comment: Maybe it's a stardate.

Comment: @DavidFaber: no, stardates are always specified with an extra decimal. It would be 41867.0 if it was a stardate. (Incidentally, it would be in 2364, between seasons 1 and 2 of TNG.)

Comment: thx u @Jeroen Mostert

Answer (score 9):

SQL Server stores dates as the number of days since 1/1/1900 with the fraction as the portion of a day.

```
declare @d1 datetime

set @d1 = 41867

select @d1

select CONVERT(varchar(20),@d1,120)
```

or if you want to do it in one statement:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(25),cast(41867 as datetime),120)
```

Comment: On my machine it printed: 2014-04-18 00:00:00 Are you running SQL Server and if so what version?

Comment: Please specify this in the future. You wasted a lot of volunteer's time. Access and Sql Server are very different products.

Answer (score 2):

This 5 digit format is called msdate and it starts from 1 Jan 1900. Easiest way to convert it into standard date is,

```
select convert(datetime, 44321) - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes 5 digit number is a datetime in Clarion datetime standard. It starts from 28 December 1800. If you have some test data you can compare expected value with data in [online calculators](https://clarioncalc.azurewebsites.net/).