# SQL date as INTEGER to PHP datetime format

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, date

I have problem to convert data saved as INTEGER in mysql server to display datetime format.

I have access to sql server view using php.

Date like:

```
2008-02-29 00:00:00.000
```

i saved like: 75668  (integer)

How to format

```
75668
```

to

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

? and

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

to this format (like 75668)?

I see that in sql server it's done like:

```
cast (a.DATA - 36163 as datetime) DATA_W
```

How can I format this value using php?

In structure this table I have :

```
[DATA] [dbo].[T_DATA_TYP] NULL,
```

this column is create bu custom type. 
Type declaration is :

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[T_DATA_TYP] FROM [int] NULL
```

Comment: What is the relationship between 75668 and 29th February 2008? Is there some kind of formula? Days since a base date?

Comment: why are you saving date time as integer data type ?? There is datatype for datetime in mysql database .

Comment: This is not my database (it's programs db) In sql server column DATA is saved by custom type 

    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[T_DATA_TYP] FROM [int] NULL

Comment: but 1204243200 is not 75668

Comment: In structure this table I have :      [DATA] [dbo].[T_DATA_TYP] NULL, this column is create bu custom type. Type declaration is : CREATE TYPE [dbo].[T_DATA_TYP] FROM [int] NULL

Comment: Is it in excel date format?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589834/simply-convert-5-digit-number-in-mysql-database-to-a-date

Comment: SQL SERVER Integer format

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: but I have to format this value in php using doctrine2. I write method getData but I don't know How to change format... I know that to display formated data in view I can use cast (a.DATA - 36163 as datetime) DATA_W. But how to do it in php?

Comment: @marczak You need to stop deflecting the questions and demonstrate the mathematical relationship between the integer 75668 and the date '2008-02-29' or no one will ever be able to give you and answer to this question. We have *no idea*. If you've simply pulled a random number and a random date out of your ass, then say so and fix your question with *real data*.

Comment: @Gene - not quite Excel, 75668 is 3rd March 2107 in MS Excel; but 75668 - 36163 is 39505, which is 27th February 2008 in MS Excel.... well done for spotting the connection

Comment: Yes this is answer to my question. Thnx.

Comment: no matter what it is.. really strange way to save a date.  I'm not 100% positive but I'd wager that all database systems have a datetime field these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's a variant of an MS Excel serialized timestamp, which is a count of the days since 31st December 1899.... if that is the case, then you can convert it to a unix timestamp using a function like:

```
function ExcelToUnixTimestamp($dateValue = 0)
{
    $excelBaseDate = 25567;

    // Perform conversion
    if ($dateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $dateValue - $excelBaseDate;
        $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    return $returnValue;
}

$weirdTimestamp = 75668;
$unixTimestamp = ExcelToUnixTimestamp($weirdTimestamp - 36163);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unixTimestamp);
```

Comment: There isn't MS Excel serialize timestamp. It's clarion format.

Answer (score 0):

This date is in CLARION format.

user this:
c#: var xx = new DateTime(1800, 12, 28).AddDays(75668);

in sql:
DECLARE @SqlDt DATETIME
SET @SqlDt = DateAdd(day, 75668, '1800-12-28')
SELECT @SqlDt AS 'SQL Date Time'